# Node.js has no method 'sendHeader'

Tags: jquery, node.js

Node.js has no method 'sendHeader'

Installation copy is from git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git

Is install inside ubunti lucid server as Amazon EC2 AMI file.

The simple say hello via command output is working.

But, when output to browser, it fail to works.

Guys, any idea to fix it?

I hope to use node.js, but seems it is not ready for production usage yet.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-129-31-63:~/Desktop/node/test3$ node hello_world_server.js
Server running at http://localhost:8080/

/home/ubuntu/Desktop/node/test3/hello_world_server.js:5
    response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
             ^
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'sendHeader'
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Desktop/node/test3/hello_world_server.js:5:14)
    at Server.emit (events.js:45:17)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1081:12)
    at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:87:31)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:980:22)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:654:27)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:156:10)
ubuntu@ip-10-129-31-63:~/Desktop/node/test3$ node -v
v0.5.0-pre
```

Code to run

```
var sys = require('sys'),
   http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  setTimeout(function () {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    res.write('<br/><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello World!</strong>');

    res.end();

  }, 2000);

}).listen(8000);

sys.puts('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
```

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/http.html#response.setHeader

Comment: it looks like you are trying out the net.tutsplus walkthrough. even in the comments section of that article it mentions the incompatibility in the newer versions. use `writeHead()` and you'll be golden.

Comment: I'm doing the http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/ and the solution was
`var sys = require("sys"),  
    http = require("http");  
      
http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");;  
    response.write("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
    response.write("<p style=\"text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px green;\">Trying to format text from server side</p>");
    response.end();  
}).listen(8080);  
  
sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "setHeader", not "sendHeader".

And no, node is not ready for production use. That doesn't stop a lot of people from using it, but even they'll tell you that they're a little crazy for doing so.

*edit* — the other answers may be right, that it may be you're looking for "writeHead()".  Since all I'm doing here is looking at the quite lovely node.js documentation at nodejs.org, I'm forced to wonder whether you've done that yet yourself.

Comment: I've just started playing with Node and I can confirm that the documentation on the site is excellent.

Answer (score 12):

If you are following the NetTuts tutorial, try:

```
response.writeHead()
```

instead of

```
response.sendHeader
```

and

```
response.end()
```

instead of

```
response.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

The function is probably called writeHead(). "Probably", because I don't know your code and what libraries you load.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/http.html#response.writeHead

Hardly no one uses node.js for a complete webserver, but for sub-functionality, e.g. chat server it's already in production use on quite a few sites.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the method is [writeHead()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/http.html#response.writeHead)